# react TextField material UI value

Tags: reactjs, input, material-ui, state

I'm using materiel UI form component in a modal.
This modal can be opened for add or edit an item, so values can be empty or not.
I put default props values in a state but this is always empty and never get previous values...
Here is my code :

```
const Comp = (props) => {
  const { edit, values } = props // edit props for editing user
  // values is :
   {
     prenom: 'name',
     nom: 'name'
   }
   // ...
   const [nom, setNom] = React.useState(edit ? values.nom : '')
   const [prenom, setPrenom] = React.useState(edit ? values.prenom : '')
   // ...
   return (
      <form>
              <TextField
                id="prenom"
                value={prenom}
                label="Prénom"
                variant="outlined"
                onChange={(event) => setPrenom(event.target.value)}
              />
              <TextField
                id="nom"
                value={nom}
                label="Nom"
                variant="outlined"
                onChange={(event) => setNom(event.target.value)}
              />
      </form>
   )
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you put your code on Codesandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you have your `Comp` used on the parent but not visible till some state changes, something like `isDialogOpen`. Then once the user wants to edit some object you do something like

```
setIsDialogOpen(true);
setDialogEditMode(true);
setValuesToEdit({nom: 'Foo', prenom: 'Bar'});
```

You have to understand that once you use the component (`<Comp prop='value' />`) React renders it, even that nothing gets to the actual Dom, the `Comp` function will be called! so at first it's being called with some empty values, then you want to let the user do the editing, you change the parent state. BUT the `Comp` state is still the state that it was created with (Empty values).

**Remember this**: `useState` acts in two ways:

- On the first render it returns the value from the given parameter.
- Any future renders it **ignores** the parameter and returns the saved state.

So in order to change the saved state you have to declare a reaction/effect when the props change, you do that with `useEffect` inside your `Comp`

for example:

```
useEffect(() => {
   setNom(values.nom);
   setPrenom(values.prenom);
}, [values])
```